# Finding a cut with maximum number of edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, genetic-algorithm

Given graph G=(V,E).
I need to find an algorithm that returns a cut of the graph with the maximal number of edges.

I would be very thankful if anyone can help me.
Thank you in advance

Comment: belongs to https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I thin you want a cut with max flow not maximum edges? This is called Max-flow min cut. Here you can get more details http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr04/cos226/lectures/maxflow.4up.pdf

Comment: No, i need maximum number of edges.
thank you anyway for your response. @LuaiGhunim

Comment: That's the [Maximum cut problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut), which is known to be NP-complete.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvbKwrlTImM

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but about a computer science (cs.stackexchange.com).